# Which splatbook describes horse breeds in the Forgotten Realms?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, dnd-3e, forgotten-realms, mount

I clearly remember one of the Forgotten Realms manuals having a list of made-up breeds with stat modifiers for each.

Which splatbook are they in?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The horse breeds are in the Champions of Valor monster section, hidden under the "Agents of Good" heading (starting on page 153).

Comment: Wow, that's a super-obscure location for something that would be widely-known by people in the setting.